# MYSQL Creating tables with foreign keys producing errors

Tags: mysql, datatable, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Trying to create a few new tables with foreign keys but am getting caught up, here's the code and the error I'm receiving, I think it has something to
do with my foreign key?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
    check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
    right syntax to use near '(`CustomerID`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 10



DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer`;
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (

    `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `Customer_Number`       VARCHAR(100), 
    `Customer_Name`         VARCHAR(100), 
    `Website`               VARCHAR(255), 
    `Logo`                  VARCHAR(100),

    PRIMARY KEY(`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Reports`;
    CREATE TABLE `Reports` (

        `ReportsID`             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        `Role`                  VARCHAR(70), 
        `Region`                VARCHAR(70), 
        `Inpection_Type`        VARCHAR(70), 
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED,
        `Report_Date`           DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
        `Order_Date`            TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        `Customer_Name`         VARCHAR(100),
        `Customer_Division`     VARCHAR(70),
        `Memo`                  VARCHAR(255),
        `Billing_Key`           VARCHAR(70),

        PRIMARY KEY(`ReportsID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CustomerContact`;
    CREATE TABLE `CustomerContact` (

        `ContactID`             INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED,
        `Division`              VARCHAR(100), 
        `Contact`               VARCHAR(100), 
        `Address`               VARCHAR(255),
        `Phone`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Fax`                   VARCHAR(100),
        `Email`                 VARCHAR(100),
        `Mobile`                VARCHAR(100),

        PRIMARY KEY(`ContactID`),
        FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Missing comma between `Logo varchar()` and `primary key`?

Comment: @biziclop Same effect after repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a missing comma after the Logo column, and a missing backtick at the end of the CustomerID column name in the foreign key definition.

Once you fix those and re-run the DDL you will discover that the CustomerContact table does not have a column named CustomerID, so you should add that, too.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Customer`;
    CREATE TABLE `Customer` ( 
        `CustomerID`            INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Customer_Number`        VARCHAR(100),
        `Customer_Name`            VARCHAR(100),
        `Website`                VARCHAR(255),
        `Logo`                    VARCHAR(100),
        PRIMARY KEY(`CustomerID`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;


    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CustomerContact`;
    CREATE TABLE `CustomerContact` (

        `ContactID`                INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Division`                VARCHAR(100),
        `Contact`                VARCHAR(100),
        `Address`                VARCHAR(255),
        `Phone`                    VARCHAR(100),
        `Fax`                    VARCHAR(100),
        `Email`                    VARCHAR(100),
        `Mobile`                VARCHAR(100),
        PRIMARY KEY(`ContactID`),
        CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma:

```
    `Logo`                    VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(`CustomerID`)
```

etc.

Also a back tick in the end:

```
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES Customer(`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Comment: I updated my code with some of the missing commas but same results

Comment: The line in the very end, you're missing a backtick (see updated response)